# Can I say "я не в доме не прыгал" meaning "за пределами дома я не прыгал"

Tags: грамматика, отрицание

Я понимаю, что в устной речи так не говорят и, более того, так, наверное, не пишут.
Но верно ли это с грамматической точки зрения, и не противоречит ли каким-то правилам.

Также интересует вариант "Я не прыгал не в доме"

Comment: С грамматической точки зрения выглядит нормально для обоих вариантов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Совершенно нормальное предложение с двойным отрицанием (double negation), обычно характерное для детской речи,когда ребенку требуется подчеркнуть важность какого-то слова.Both fronting and emphasis are used.The meaning is usually positive and opposite because it's one of thosr cases when "negative "+"negative "gives "plus"(giving the affirmative sense). That said, your sentence means

> Я не в доме не прыгал = Я прыгал только в доме.

Adults also use it sometimes

> не мог не посмотреть (значит посмотрел), не смог не взять (значит взял).